# Can I set up 2 SignalR connections?

Tags: signalr

I have a basic chat app set up like so:

```
$(function () {
// Set up references for other functions to call
   chatConnection = $.connection.chatHub;
   // Set up callbacks before starting server connection
   chatConnection.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
      var prettyMessage = name + ':' + message;
      $('#chatHistory').append(prettyMessage);
      $("#chatHistory").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatHistory').prop("scrollHeight") }, 10);
   };
   // Start up connection to server, set up events
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      $('#sendChatButton').click(function () {
        // Call the Send method on the hub.
        chatConnection.server.sendMessage($('#displayName').val(), $('#chatBox').val());
        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
        $('#chatBox').val('').focus();
      });
   });
});
```

This calls into my ChatHub.cs server side and I am getting and passing back messages as you would expect.

```
public void SendMessage(string name, string message)
{
    Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
}
```

Now I want to add functionality. I Have a new class almost identical to my ChatHub called "GameHub" and it's job is to process moves instead of processing chat. So far I have something like this:

```
$(function () {
// Set up references for other functions to call
   chatConnection = $.connection.chatHub;
   gameConnection = $.connection.gameHub;
   // Set up callbacks before starting server connection
   chatConnection.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
      var prettyMessage = name + ':' + message;
      $('#chatHistory').append(prettyMessage);
      $("#chatHistory").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatHistory').prop("scrollHeight") }, 10);
   };
   gameConnection.client.receiveMove = function (name, move){
      alert(name + ' played ' + move);
   };
   // Start up connection to server, set up events
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      $('#sendChatButton').click(function () {
        // Call the Send method on the hub.
        chatConnection.server.sendMessage($('#displayName').val(), $('#chatBox').val());
        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
        $('#chatBox').val('').focus();
      });
      $('#sendMoveButton').click(function () {
        gameConnection.server.sendMove(getMove());
      });
   });
});
```

but nothing is making it to the server. Is this because I don't have it set up correct? Can signalR even support 2 hubs or should it be a single hub and "spoke" out from there to my 2 different functional areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but given that there is no performance difference it's simpler to have those functions in one hub. All data will hit all hubs as they all share the same connection.

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiple-hubs).

You can check, since it's not provided, your game hub and method to ensure you have them named and cased properly on the server side. Possible issues...